# Normal Sleeping Heart Rate Range

Tags: sleep, heart, heart-rate

I recently got a heart rate tracker and I've noticed that when I sleep my heart rate consistently spikes fairly high.  It has reached 165 bpm before, but most times it's under 150. That seems a bit counter intuitive to me, especially since I'm a physically active male in my twenties and when I took a light jog the other day my heart rate only got up to 110. That got me thinking, what's a normal heart rate range for someone while they are asleep?

Comment: It's very individualized but certainly well under 100 in a healthy individual. Think 50-70 or thereabouts. Your monitor is either very inaccurate or you need to see a cardiologist.

Comment: @CareyGregory I'm pretty sure you're right my monitorr was inaccurate. I got a new one and the results are more inline with what you said. My hear rate is typically between 50-60, occasionally spikes into the 70, occasionally dips into the 40s, and rarely below that. One time it did register as 25-26, but that may have been a bad reading.